# Combining/merging observables

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, observable, rxjs5

Suppose I'm developing a chat app. I have observable `threads$` that emits array of threads every *n* seconds, observable `offline$` that notifies when a thread became offline, observable `online$` that notifies when a thread became online:

```
enum ConnectionStatus { Offline = 0, Online }

interface Thread {
    id: string;
    status: ConnectionStatus
}

const threads$ = Observable
    .interval(n)
    .switchMap(() => Observable.create((observer: Observer<Array<Thread>>) =>
        getThreads((threads: Array<Thread>) => observer.next(threads))));

const online$ = Observable.create((observer: Observer<Thread>) =>
    onOnline((threadId: string) => observer.next({
        id: threadId,
        status: ConnectionStatus.Online
    })));

const offline$ = Observable.create((observer: Observer<Thread>) =>
    onOffline((threadId: string) => observer.next({
        id: threadId,
        status: ConnectionStatus.Offline
    })));
```

I want to combine these streams following this *rule*: `threads$` should emit array every n seconds, but whenever `online$` or `offline$` emits, I want to grab latest value(`Array<Threads>`) of `threads$` and map it by changing status of one thread and emit mapped collection immediately.

I've lost track with Rx's `combineLatest`, `mergeMap`, `zip` and similar, so I would appreciate if someone could help me to implement combining in this case(in more of a Rx-way)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should emit an `Array<Thread>` every time `threads$` emits **and** immediately when `online$` and `offline$` emits.

```
const threadUpdate$ = Observable.merge(
    threads$,
    Observable.merge(online$, offline$)
        .withLatestFrom(threads$,
            (thread, threads) => threads.map(t => {
                if(t.id === thread.id) {
                    t.status = thread.status
                }
            })));
```

Note that `threads$` will continue to emit and might even emit at, potentially, the same time as the combined `online$`/`offline$` stream.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could make it like this using [`multicast()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-multicast):

```
const stop$ = Observable.merge(online$, offline$);
threads$
    .multicast(new Subject(), obs => Observable.merge(obs, obs.takeUntil(stop$).takeLast(1).map(...)))
    .subscribe(...);
```

I obviously didn't test it but maybe it'll push you the right direction.